# Spring boot Maven use same jar with different version in multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

We have quite a strange requirement.

Spring boot  with multiple  project

**xbean is old version of xmlbeans apache jar**

We want to use both

1. xbean old jar with some custom changes in the same jar
2. latest xmlbeans apache jar

we have current implementation as

Main() -

|- XLSImportProject project- which requires latest jar for reading xlsx file

|- B project - which requires old jar for custom operation

|- C project - also require old jar for custom operation

If we give maven priority to **xbean old jar** then we will get exception as

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:180)
```

If we give maven **priority to latest xmlbeans** then it will be errors as:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.getParent()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;
```

We have to use old xbean jar in sub project and latest xmlbeans jar in other project.

But Spring will always the jar which is define first in dependency.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a classical classloader customization problem. I wouldn't go down that road. Best suggestion would be

1. create your own jar with all dependencies (tricky since you will face the problems of backward compatibility). Take a look [here](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) for repackaging jars.
2. Break away the multi module project into different projects with each set of projects using a particular dependency.

Comment: I have change the requirement into different projects as well as the dependencies are added in the required project only. but as mine is spring boot application, it is considering all the dependecies in main project and then it will not able to different which jar is specific to which project

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). It rename the packages if required based on the content of the jar. Create `Uber jar` for your main application using `shade plugin`.

Shade plugin configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: But as mine is spring boot application , it will consider all the dependencies to be in main class project and from there only it will refer.. and it will consider  first priority dependency

Comment: Also both are same jars and packaging of both the jar are same then i am not sure this approach will work ?